# ng-bind failing when using a custom filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, filter, ng-bind

I've looked through a number of responses and can't for the life of me figure out why my code isn't working!

I want to apply a simple custom filter to a variable passed from the controller. The `room-price` value displays fine. however, when I add the `price-per-night` filter the value disappears.

Can anyone suggest a solution? 
Thanks

**Template**

```
<div class="h3 left-align p1" ng-bind="room.price | price-per-night"></div>
```

**Controller**

```
routerApp.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
    $scope.rooms = [
    {
        name: 'Basic',
        price: 50
    }]
});
```

**Filter**

```
routerApp.filter("price-per-night",
    function() {
        return function(price) {
            var output = '£' + price + ' ' + 'per night';
            return output;
        };
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name your filter `pricePerNight`. `-` is not allowed in the name:

```
routerApp.filter("pricePerNight",
    function() {
        return function(price) {
            var output = '£' + price + ' ' + 'per night';
            return output;
        };
    }
);
```

(You still use `price-per-night` in your HTML)